# Multivariable Calc. Continuity at Origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Check if f(x,y) is continous at the origin.
$f(x,y)=\frac { x{ \left| y \right|  }^{ \alpha  } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } } \quad ;\quad { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 }\neq 0\\ 
\alpha >0$

I'm having way to much trouble than i should with the Absolute Value.
Trys with squeeze Theorem.
$\frac { x{ \left| y \right|  }^{ \alpha  } }{ { x }^{ 2 }{ +y }^{ 2 } } \le \frac { x{ \left| y \right|  }^{ \alpha  } }{ { x }^{ 2 } } =\frac { { \left| y \right|  }^{ \alpha  } }{ x } $ obviously doesnt work.

${ \left| y \right|  }^{ \alpha  }>0\quad ->\\ \frac { x{ y }^{ \alpha  } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } } \le \frac { x{ y }^{ \alpha  } }{ { y }^{ 2 } } =x{ y }^{ \alpha -2 }$

would work but I dont think the condition is valid.
Could somebody show me hot to squezze. Or give me a possible way with Epsilon-Delta

Comment: Think of a common coordinate system we use (other than cartesian)

Comment: Polarcoordiantes, does the ABS vanish if i use them? If so how would be the geometric explanation?

Comment: Try plotting it for $\alpha=1$. Should give you an indication of what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a value of $f(x,y)$ at the origin firstly,to check the continuity.

If you take polar coordinates: $$x=r \cos{t}$$ $$y=r \sin{t}$$

Then the $f(r,t)= \frac{r^{a+1}\cos{t}\sin^a{t}}{r^2}=r^{a-1}\cos{t}\sin^a{t}$

If $a=1$ the limit does not exist.

If $a>1$ the limit is zero,as $r \to 0^+$

If $a<1$ the limit does not exist.

Comment: My bad, f(x,y)=0 if f=y=0 but conditions hold true anyways. Thanks for help

Comment: @johnka...Ok if you define your function like this the the function is continuous only when $a>1$..in the other cases of $a$ whatever you do to the value of the function at the origin,the limit will not exist at the origin

Comment: right. last question, if a=1 my function is undefinied hence the limit can't exist doesnt have something to do with actually taking the limit right?

Comment: If $a=1$ then $f(r,t)=\cos\{t}\sin{t}$  as $r \to 0$..but in order for the limit to exist the result must be independent of $t$..so here for different $t$ you have different results thus the limit does not exist

Comment: Thanks for the help and time